# Checkboxes in while loop won't give value

Tags: php, jquery, database

I'm trying to get all the values of my selected checkboxes into a textarea. The checkboxes and their values are taken from a DB. I don't know why, but the only thing my textarea is giving me is the word 'on' when something is selected.

these are the checkboxes:

```
 <div class="controls" id="c_b">
        <?php
            echo "<ul>";
            while($user = $allUsers->fetch_assoc())
            {
                echo "<li><input type='checkbox'> " . $user['username'] . " </input></li>";
            }
            echo "</ul>";
            ?>
            <br />
            </div>
```

and this is the function:

```
function updateTextArea() {         
     var allVals = [];
     $('#c_b :checked').each(function() {
       allVals.push($(this).val());
     });
     $('#t').val(allVals)
  }
 $(function() {
   $('#c_b input').click(updateTextArea);
   updateTextArea();
 });
```

thanks in advance,
I hope somebody can see what I'm missing! 
Jana

Comment: try ....  <input type='checkbox' value='$user['username']'> " . $user['username'] . " </input>

Answer (score 2):

If you don't set a value on a checkbox, it will default to `on` if checked. You need to set the value to each username.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="bob" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You may add the attribute value to the checkbox: http://jsfiddle.net/RNdFS/

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
     $('#c_b input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
       allVals.push($(this).val());
     });
```

Comment: Thank you! Yours wasn't the solution, but you made me find it!

I hadn't given any value to my checkboxes so I had to add that and the thing worked like a charm! Thanks!